# MaximumSubsequenceSum - output not correct

Tags: python, algorithm

For a consecutive subsequence, we should expect a max sum of 20. Consecutive in the sense that 1,2,3 not 1,3,5.

I've attempted to implement this but am having trouble with the output.

```
def maxSubsequenceSum(a):
    maxSum = 0
    i=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        j=i
        for j in range(len(a)):

            thisSum = 0

            k=i

            for k in range(j+1):
                thisSum += a[k]

            if thisSum > maxSum:
                maxSum = thisSum
                seqStart = i
                seqEnd = j
                
    return maxSum,seqStart,seqEnd
```

I tried a = [-2,11,-4,13,-5,2] then
maxSubsequenceSum(a) should output 20, 1, 3. But it  is outputting 18,0,3.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `j=i` has no effect because `for j in range(len(a))` starts counting from `0`. You mean `for j in range(i, len(a))`. Same for `k = i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
from itertools import combinations

a = [-2, 11, -4, 13, -5, 2]

out = max(
    (sum(a[start:end]), start, end - 1)
    for start, end in combinations(range(len(a) + 1), 2)
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
(20, 1, 3)
```